# Can I use Git tfs to re-migrate to an existing git repo

Tags: git-tfs

I want to move tfvc to tfs git. 
I am going to use git tfs tool
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md

After I push to origin there will be some more checkinswto tfvc, therefore I want to re-migrate. Is it possible, or this only supports migrating to a empty repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't re-migrate in an existing repository. You need ans empty folder.

But there is better. You simply don't have to re-migrate!

If you don't clean the necessary git-tfs metadata ( described in https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#clean-commits-optional ) that will prevent git-tfs to work, you can just fetch the new changes and push them to the git repository. That's the normal behavior of git-tfs.

Just do:

```
git tfs pull
git push YOUR_GIT_REMOTE
```